# Can't get AutoCAD DWG's with AEC objects to load into Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Specifically an AutoCAD drawing containing AEC objects. Starts the load process, but never returns, leaving us hanging. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Most likely it is not supported by the translator... you could check the manifest endpoint that may return an error code and a message: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET.

Comment: The "AEC Object" sounds like a Custom Entity of the AutoCAD. If I'm correct, you have to install `Object Enablers` which fits your AutoCAD version. Afterward, open your drawings and execute command `ExportToAutoCAD` to convert Custom Entities to the common Entities.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-6515268E-3D71-4CBC-8D3C-2059CFAA4E38-htm.html